# Is it inappropriate to flag moderator to unwiki an answer with many substantial revisions by the author?

Tags: discussion, flags, community-wiki

Recently, I came across a community wiki answer which was very detailed and comprehensive. Checking the revision history, I couldn't see any evidence of the author making it a community wiki (which would show as **[Post made Community Wiki]** in the revision comment), so I flagged the question to ask the moderator to unwiki the answer. However, my flag was rejected.

(The link to the answer is hidden in the Markdown source of this question. Let us focus on the general case, rather than a single case.)

Is is appropriate to flag moderator to unwiki such answer? I have seen such precedence on other sites in the network.

Comment: I had success flagging for this, although when it's not very straightforward or when reasoning to un-wiki is too large to fit into 500 chars flag message, it could be more convenient to raise meta post ([1](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5496/31260 "example"), [2](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/3527/31260 "example"))

Comment: There are 3 ways it can become a community wiki. The other 2 are "A moderator has reason to believe that the post serves better in community wiki mode" and "When a moderator converts a question to community wiki, all existing answers will also be converted in addition to converting future answers." from [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741). Either of these could apply to your hidden question.

Answer (score 18):

I have had success the one and only time I flagged one of my own answers on Stack Overflow that had become CW due to automatic triggers (which were triggered by me). But as mentioned in the [SE wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/146015) these automatic triggers are no longer operational so it requires an act of clumsiness for a post to become CW unintentionally. In other words, don't flag it because it was a deliberate action that made it that way.

That still leaves all the older posts that became CW due to the old editing triggers. Personally I would say that you shouldn't flag those either **unless you are the author**. Those posts were CW'd when it was a fundamental part of the fabric of the site, and the same rules applied to everyone.

I mod on a different site, and I can say that if I processed a flag requesting to un-wiki a post I would consider carefully, and the threshold that needs to be passed would be high. You would have to be either the author with a moderately good excuse, if you weren't the author then you would have to have a quite compelling reason. Having said that, each moderator (and indeed each site) will have a slightly different take on it. I'm an old timer on the site and a bit more traditional so I'm harder to persuade.

*for newer members CW == "community wiki"

Comment: This is probably the best policy. We don't need people writing queries to hunt for these just for something to flag, and they don't really need to be un-wiki'd unless it's bothering the author of the post.

Comment: I also tend to leave this up to the author because sometimes I've found people who wanted their posts to be left as community wiki. If the author flags their own post, or somehow indicates that they didn't want this status, great, but I probably wouldn't accept a flag from someone other than the author asking for a conversion.

Comment: @Brad Larson: I declined such a flag just yesterday.

Comment: @canon That scenario can no longer happen as the edit related triggers for CW have been removed. And if it has happened sometime in the past then so be it. I can't say that *everyone* knew about the CW by cumulative edits feature but it certainly wasn't unknown and there was a steady stream of questions in Meta about it. I would consider that specific scenario a non-issue.

Comment: @canon Yep, if it wasn't flagged at the time then that's pretty much the way it stays. I do remember seeing posts on Meta discussing whether a specific question should be CW, usually people were asking for it to be made CW rather than the other way round. I would suggest that some of the other sites may have mods that are newer members so they could have a different view point about it.

Comment: @canon - For the record, we have had people who were perfectly fine with the wiki status of their answers. I'm content to let people bring this to our attention themselves, and to act on their wishes.

Comment: @canon: I have had it happen to one of my answers, couldn't figure out why (at least now I know from reading this), but really don't mind. It seems more productive to find something else to answer than to raise a flag to quibble over maybe +50 rep.