# Why setting a question as un-community wiki does not affect answers?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Seems that if a question was automatically turned into community wiki during automatic triggers era, all the attached answers were also affected and made community wiki. (at least for 30+ answers trigger).

Why un-community wiki the question (by a mod) doesn't apply for the answers as well? Should they all be actually flagged one by one, and manually set by a mod? Seems redundant to me, considering the thread as a whole got to become community-wiki altogether.

Example: Got my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14415881/572670) back into "regular question", and was hoping @usr (and others, but mostly him) will also get the credit he deserves for [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14419556/572670). I was surprised to see that the question is "regular question", yet all the answers are still community wiki.

Comment: You can flag the answer for a moderator attention and ask them to un-wiki it.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I know I *can*, but not sure if I *should* in the first place. what is the reason making the question non community wiki is not tied with making the answers as well?

Comment: I think you should.. I remember I saw similar discussion in some thread, will look for it.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288733/is-it-inappropriate-to-flag-moderator-to-unwiki-an-answer-with-many-substantial